# Building a site with Twig PHP Template Engine

Tags: php, twig

I've read through the documentation for [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), but I don't quite understand how to connect the dots.

Let's say I create a file `index.php` which instantiates the `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` and `Twig_Environment` classes. I can load one template here using `loadTemplate()`.

Individual page content is stored in `.phtml` or `.html.twig` files, which may link to other pages on the site. However, those would always link to another .php file, not the template.

What is the best way to abstract this process, so that I only need one php file for multiple templates? Htaccess? Some sort of router class? Are there any examples out there?

Comment: if its similar to the template smarty, how it works is, the template files have the html and javascript, and the php files call them, the data is connected using a data-link built into the template.  The advantage of templates is they seperate the php from the html.  You link to the php file because hte php file is what calls the html, the html would have no dynamic data to output without the php file which does all the server side processing.

Comment: I understand why I need to call the PHP file. However, how should the server side be organized to obviate the need for a php file for each template?

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking, the way that I use smarty is, every template file has its own php file, you browse to the php file, it loads all the necessary data, then calls the template file, and outputs the data to the user.  With templates, you still need seperate php files for each page.

Comment: Are you using some kind of MVC framework or just a bunch of PHP files?

Comment: @JimmyBanks I haven't used Smarty before, so that's good to know for sake of comparison.

Comment: @galymzhan Not currently using a framework. Just want to use the template engine across a bunch of php files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using several PHP files then it's wise to create template renderer class, which will bootstrap Twig classes, set options and take care of finding and rendering requested templates:

```
<?php
// Use correct path to Twig's autoloader file
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
// Twig's autoloader will take care of loading required classes
Twig_Autoloader::register();

class TemplateRenderer
{
  public $loader; // Instance of Twig_Loader_Filesystem
  public $environment; // Instance of Twig_Environment

  public function __construct($envOptions = array(), $templateDirs = array())
  {
    // Merge default options
    // You may want to change these settings
    $envOptions += array(
      'debug' => false,
      'charset' => 'utf-8',
      'cache' => './cache', // Store cached files under cache directory
      'strict_variables' => true,
    );
    $templateDirs = array_merge(
      array('./templates'), // Base directory with all templates
      $templateDirs
    );
    $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($templateDirs);
    $this->environment = new Twig_Environment($this->loader, $envOptions);
  }

  public function render($templateFile, array $variables)
  {
    return $this->environment->render($templateFile, $variables);
  }
}
```

Don't copy-paste, this is just an example, your implementation may be different depending on your needs. Save this class somewhere

### Usage

I'm going to assume that you have a directory structure similar to this:

```
/home/www/index.php
/home/www/products.php
/home/www/about.php
```

Create directories under webserver's root dir (`/home/www` in this case):

```
/home/www/templates # this will store all template files
/home/www/cache # cached templates will reside here, caching is highly recommended
```

Put your template files under `templates` directory

```
/home/www/templates/index.twig
/home/www/templates/products.twig
/home/www/templates/blog/categories.twig # Nested template files are allowed too
```

Now sample index.php file:

```
<?php
// Include our newly created class
require_once 'TemplateRenderer.php';

// ... some code

$news = getLatestNews(); // Pulling out some data from databases, etc
$renderer = new TemplateRenderer();
// Render template passing some variables and print it
print $renderer->render('index.twig', array('news' => $news));
```

Other PHP files will be similar.

### Notes

Change settings/implementation to suit your needs. You may want to restrict web access to the `templates` directory (or even put it somewhere outside), otherwise everyone will be able to download template files.

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for. Thanks.